# SQL select query with not not in clause

Tags: sql, select, mysqli

I have a table structure like this way

```
CREATE TABLE `fb_requests`
(                                              
     `id` int(60) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `user_id` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,
     `fb_user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `request_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `game_selected` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,
     `accept_status` int(60) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = pending 1 = accept', 2 = reject
     `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=187 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There is a `accept_status` columns that contains 0,1,2 statuses

To get desired data I am writing three queries first query fetch accept status = 1 rows

```
select 
    fb_user_id, accept_status 
from  
    fb_requests 
where
    user_id = 17 
    and accept_status = 1 
    and game_selected = 2 
group by 
    fb_user_id;
```

Second query fetch accept status = 2

```
select 
    fb_user_id, accept_status 
from  
    fb_requests 
where
    user_id = 17 
    and accept_status = 2 
    and game_selected = 2 
group by 
    fb_user_id;
```

In third query I need to fetch rows which are not in earlier queries, so I used a `not in` clause.

```
select 
    fb_user_id, accept_status 
from 
    fb_requests 
where
    user_id = 17 
    and accept_status = 0 
    and game_selected = 5 
    and fb_user_id not in (select fb_user_id 
                           from  fb_requests 
                           where user_id = 17
                             and accept_status = 2  
                             and game_selected = 5 
                             and fb_user_id not in (select fb_user_id 
                                                    from fb_requests 
                                                    where user_id = 17
                                                      and accept_status = 1
                                                      and game_selected = 5)
                          )  
group by 
       fb_user_id
```

But something is not right in the case of third query, am not getting desired result. Am not sure this is the way combine two not in clauses.  I need to get an array with no duplication of fb_user_id between these queries.

Am expecting this type of a query first take

```
$query = select fb_user_id,accept_status from fb_requests where
                          user_id= 17 and accept_status=0 and game_selected=2 and
                          fb_user_id not in (select fb_user_id from  fb_requests where user_id= 17
                          and accept_status=1  and game_selected=2 )  group by fb_user_id

and then $query not in select fb_user_id from  fb_requests where user_id= 17
                          and accept_status=2  and game_selected=2
```

Please help me to find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    fb_user_id, accept_status 
from 
    fb_requests 
where
    user_id = 17 
    and accept_status = 0 
    and game_selected = 5 
    and fb_user_id not in (select fb_user_id 
                           from fb_requests 
                           where user_id = 17
                             and (accept_status = 2 or accept_status = 1)  
                             and game_selected = 5)  
group by 
    fb_user_id, accept_status
```

Comment: Thank you so much Eric, You saved my life..its working in all tested cases.. i have to do more test...i will accept your answer. Once again thank you so much..